# Naming a New Sheet with Google Scripts from a specific cell on a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

trying to figure out how to give a new sheet that is copied into a folder a specific name each time from a button script. The specific name would come from a specific cell each time.

Here's the current code being used and the New Sheet is what I'm trying to have named from cell B3 on a specific spreadsheet each time. No idea how to do this, it just names it NEW SHEET each time and then errors out when I try to do B3.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder Name"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("Folder Name").makeCopy('NEW SHEET', destFolder); 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NEW SHEET').setName('Specific Sheet!B3')
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const name = sh.getRange('A1').getDisplayValue();
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder Id"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("file id").makeCopy(name, destFolder); 
}
```

Get used to using file id's and not names.

Comment: This changed the name of the sheet, but didn't clone it and name that new sheet. It just changed the name of the original.

Comment: I just tested it again and it works for me.  Perhaps you file and folder id's are not correct and I'm also getting the new file name from the active sheet.